# Match file within nested witin specific folder

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I am trying to match viable `package.json` files to get all modules in a directory, including nested ones. I ran into an issue where someone has a two `package.json` files in their module. One is in the root and one is nested. I'd like to only match the regex with the first line and not the second. Do I have to parse the strings into arrays with `path.sep` or can I do this solely with regex?

```
/Users/thomas/Desktop/exmaple/node_modules/stream-http/package.json
/Users/thomas/Desktop/exmaple/node_modules/stream-http/test/browser/package.json
```

Pattern

```
^.+\/node_modules\/.+\/package.json$
```

https://regexr.com/45qvr

Comment: If you can count on it existing directly inside a directory inside `node_modules`, just repeat non-`/` characters? `[^\/]+` instead of `.+`

Comment: `^.+\/node_modules\/[^\/]+\/package.json$`

Answer (score 0):

Using `.+` greedily catches any characters, so it will always match as much as possible to find a `package.json` at the end. If you use `[^\/]+` instead, it will only match characters that are not `/`, making sure that the `package.json` is only matched after exactly one directory under the `node_modules/`.

```
^.+\/node_modules\/[^\/]+\/package.json$
```